# Receive Object in a Stream from Siddhi

Tags: object, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have a Siddhi extension that return the next information for example:

```
{
 "licenseKey": "WxyzChXjhJ-dgjfZfHnL9-bWd4e2vxjD-eIs5hDu0To-VOxL111BAj",
 "siteUrl": "http://www.URL.net/",
 "clientPublicId": "CLIENT1",
 "host": "www.urlclient.net"
}

{
 "licenseKey": "WxyzChXjhJ-dgjfZfHnL9-bWd4e2vxjD-eIs5hDu0To-VOxL111BAj",
 "siteUrl": "http://www.URL2.net/",
 "clientPublicId": "CLIENT2",
 "host": "www.urlclient2.net"
}
```

I want store this information in a Stream and I want filter information using the atribute "clientPublicId".

I am using the next code, wlist:whitelist() is my extension Siddhi.

```
from sensorStream[temperature>98.6]
select wlist:whitelist() AS arreglo
insert into outputStream;
```

My problem is that outputStream is created with an attribute named "arreglo", so I cant filter by clientPublicId.

Can you help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process JSON or XML in Siddhi, Then you can use 'map' extension support in Siddhi for this. You can create a map using `map:createFromJSON(<string> JSONstring)` and then access the values via `map:get(<Map> map, <Object> key)`. Note you have to cast the output of the map before using it, with `cast(<object> toBeCasted, <string> castTo)`.

E.g : `cast(map:get(dataMap, 'clientPublicId'),'string')`

Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: Is posible receive a json array with a stream and after filter information?